# Display chinese characters on Windows XP

Tags: wpf, windows, internationalization

My WPF application needs to display chinese characters.

Things work perfectly when running on Windows 7.

However, when running the exact same application on Windows XP, the UI shows a series on squares instead of the chinese characters.

In both cases, no chinese system package was installed.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install fonts that can display Chinese glyphs, not present by default.  IIRC, Control Panel + Regional and Languages Options, Language tab, Install files for East Asian languages checkbox.  Ask at superuser.com if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

There's no issue with .net or XP. The problem is with the font. You need to make sure that you are using a font which contains all the glyphs that you wish to display.